# Balanced Data Distributor in BIML

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, biml

Is there support for the balanced data distributor component in BIML?
The documentation has this:
https://varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstBalancedDataDistributorNode

But when I use this element, I get the following error:

`Error  0   FlowFramework, Version=5.0.60425.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=015f370a62f9a1a3. No translator was found for the component Data Distributor of type AstBalancedDataDistributorNode in Dataflow ...`

My biml looks like this:

```
<BalancedDataDistributor Name="Data Distributor">
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Insert Row Count.Output"/>
    <OutputPaths>
        <OutputPath Name="DD1" />
        <OutputPath Name="DD2" />
        <OutputPath Name="DD3" />
        <OutputPath Name="DD4" />
        <OutputPath Name="DD5" />
    </OutputPaths>
</BalancedDataDistributor>
```

I found this example, which seems to treat it as a custom component.  Perhaps this was before it was built into SSIS: http://www.bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/82
It does not work in SQL 2016 - BIML will generate it, but it has the wrong icon on the task and it can't find the component when you try to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work using this snippet as a template:
http://www.bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/82

To make it work for my version of SSDT, I had to update the ComponentClassId as noted below (`487806FB-4C3B-4DCD-B91D-62CAAE06D460` to `C925C2DD-D414-4F4D-942E-F4F3E4871666`).  The former may be from SQL 2014

```
<CustomComponent Name="Data Distributor" ComponentClassId="C925C2DD-D414-4F4D-942E-F4F3E4871666" ComponentTypeName="Balanced Data Distributor" ContactInfo="Balanced Data Distributor;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SqlServer; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0">
    <InputPaths>
        <InputPath OutputPathName="Insert Row Count.Output" Identifier="Data Distributor Input"/>
    </InputPaths>
    <OutputPaths>
        <OutputPath Name="DD1" ErrorOrTruncationOperation="" SynchronousInput="Data Distributor Input" ExclusionGroup="1"/>
        <OutputPath Name="DD2" ErrorOrTruncationOperation="" SynchronousInput="Data Distributor Input" ExclusionGroup="1"/>
        <OutputPath Name="DD3" ErrorOrTruncationOperation="" SynchronousInput="Data Distributor Input" ExclusionGroup="1"/>
        <OutputPath Name="DD4" ErrorOrTruncationOperation="" SynchronousInput="Data Distributor Input" ExclusionGroup="1"/>
        <OutputPath Name="DD5" ErrorOrTruncationOperation="" SynchronousInput="Data Distributor Input" ExclusionGroup="1"/>
    </OutputPaths>
</CustomComponent>
```